# How to use RE2 in c++ application in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, re2

I'm new to both C++ and RE2, so it will be helpful if experts could point me to some kind of tutorial on how to use re2 it. I use Netbeans for development, and I don't know how to add RE2 library in C++ project. I need useful comments and advice.